# CentOS7 full disk encryption

Tags: encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I have one physical server and would like to configure full disk encryption for it.

First I was playing around with an virtual machines (CentOS7) and have enabled it during installation:

[image]

On reboot I get the following prompt and can successfully unlock the drive:[image]

```
[root@srv~]# lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                                          8:2    0   19G  0 part
  └─luks-9ca13c53-317d-42c5-a3ea-c6039274bf38 253:0    0   19G  0 crypt
    ├─centos_otrs-root                        253:1    0   17G  0 lvm   /
    └─centos_otrs-swap                        253:2    0    2G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sr0                                            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

AFAICS the `boot`partition is not encrypted. How could I possibly perform a true full disk encryption and still be able to use the crypt-ssh dracut module for remote unlocking of systems with disk encryption via ssh.

Thanks!

Comment: You get a chicken-and-egg problem: how to decrypt the code that will decrypt the next stage since that code is encrypted? At which layer will you stop?

Answer (score 0):

From https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/dracut/dracut.html#_crypto_luks

```
dracut --add ssh initramfs.img
dracut --add crypt initramfs.img
```